"If someone does ..., they have to ..."
I'm trying to write "If students break uniform rules, they must clean/ do cleaning" I got stuck and tried using deepl for part of the translation so I got this "生とがせいふくのきそくをやぶったばあいは" (only using the kanji I know) is this right?

What do you mean by 'uniform rules'? If it is せいふく, you have to rephrase it e.g. as if they don't wear uniform=もしせいとがせいふくをきなかったばあいは.
